# como quitar elemento de la barra de titulo de un jinternalframe

Tags: java, apache-netbeans

En la JInternalFrame estoy intentando quitar un botón que se encuentra en la parte izquierda de la ventana ya que lo encuentro repetitivo si simplemente marco la opción "closable" en las propiedades de la ventana.

en el constructor de la ventana interna puse

```
this.setDesktopIcon(null);
```

Obviamente no es lo recomendado y esto lo intente sin encontrar alguna refencia del uso del jinternalframe

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como lograr de que este botón no aparezca?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Imagino que setDesktopIcon no te ha funcionado, y la razón por la que dices que no es recomendado es por que el javadoc dice "This API should NOT BE USED by Swing applications" en la clase JDesktopIcon (parámetro). Puedes intentar con `internalFrame.setFrameIcon(null);` que en este caso debe desaparecer debido a que es nulo, pero también se puede utilizar para agregar un icono personalizado.

Comment: Si intente eso pero no es el Icono lo que deseo quitar... sino más a la izquierda está un botón de una flecha hacia abajo lo cuál abre un menú  con actividades del jinternal fram que son: restore, minimize, close, entre otras más.

Comment: Las decoraciones de ventana son muy dependientes del sistema operativo, e incluso del L&F. No reconozco cuáles usas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El botón de la izquierda aparece cuando se utiliza la apariencia `NimbusLookAndFeel`, en cualquier otro L&F puede que aparezca otra cosa o directamente que no haya nada (ej: MetalLookAndFeel). Como dijo @Sal en los comentarios, "Las decoraciones de ventana son muy dependientes del sistema operativo, e incluso del L&F.".

Por otro lado, sabiendo que estas utilizando `Nimbus` como apariencia, se puede tratar de "borrar" el botón utilizando las propiedades del UIManager de Nimbus.

```
NimbusLookAndFeel nimbusLookAndFeel = new NimbusLookAndFeel();

String property = "InternalFrame:InternalFrameTitlePane:\"InternalFrameTitlePane.menuButton\".icon";
nimbusLookAndFeel.getDefaults().put(property, null);

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(nimbusLookAndFeel);
```

El código remplaza el `Icon` que debería contener el botón "menuButton" que está dentro de la clase [`SynthInternalFrameTitlePane`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthInternalFrameTitlePane.java#L45) de Java. Con eso ya funcionaría, pero...

El código de Swing parece que hace magia, pero por lo que entiendo el botón puede tener dos diferentes "iconos".

1. Obteniéndolo de alguna manera desde esa propiedad.
2. Obteniendo el icono de la ventana. Ver: [`updateMenuIcon()`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/synth/SynthInternalFrameTitlePane.java#L343)

Eso quiere decir que si le agregas un icono personalizado a la ventana con el método [setFrameIcon(Icon icon)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html#setFrameIcon-javax.swing.Icon-) el botón tomará ese icono y por ende también podrá abrir el menú contextual al hacer click.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces si el botón toma el icono de la ventana, también te podría dar una idea de que creando un icono vació 0x0 pixeles en teoría debería eliminar el botón con el icono. Esto te podría servir si solo quieres eliminar el icono a un **JInternalFrame** especifico.

```
internalFrame.setFrameIcon(new ImageIcon());
```

También podes ver las propiedades de cada componente de Java Swing utilizando la herramienta https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/ que ha sido nombrada en muchos posts de StackOverFlow en ingles.